# Orgmode exporting table to csv throws error

Tags: emacs, export-to-csv, org-mode

I have this code which used to work with `org-table-export`, but now It throws an error message at me: 
'No such transformation function csv'

```
#+PROPERTY: table_export_file filename.csv
#+PROPERTY: TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT csv
| 1 | 2 |
| a | b |
```

What could be wrong? I'm on Org 8.3.4 with ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by trying to change the default value for the variable with `M-x customize variable RET org-table-export-..` (Tab completion), which showed me that I had apparently set it wrong to start with; my property should have looked the following way:

```
#+PROPERTY: TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT orgtbl-to-csv
```

Mystery solved.